# ASP.NET Display File from FileUpload Control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an HTML page (OK, ASP.NET) with a [FileUpload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx) control.

```
<asp:GridView ID="DocGrid" ShowFooter="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server" DataKeyNames="doc_id,req_id,doc_name,doc_path" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" BorderColor="Silver" Width="500px" BackColor="White">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="Document">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" Text='<%# Bind("doc_name") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# Bind("doc_path") %>' Target="_blank" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
      </ItemTemplate>
      <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="fuFooter" runat="server" Width="350px" />
      </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

That isn't all of the HTML, but it should be everything needed to understand the question.

In VB code behind, the uploaded files are correctly saved using this bit of code:

```
Dim fuFooter As FileUpload = CType(DocGrid.FooterRow.FindControl("fuFooter"), FileUpload)
If (fuFooter.HasFile) Then
  Dim uploadDir As String = Server.MapPath(VIRTUAL_REC_DOCS)
  If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(uploadDir) Then
    Dim item As New ReqDoc()
    item.doc_name = fuFooter.FileName
    item.doc_path = uploadDir & fuFooter.FileName
    fuFooter.SaveAs(item.doc_path)
    item.req_id = Request.QueryString("Req_id")
    DocReqManager.insertReqDoc(item)
    bindDocGridgrid()
  End If
Else
  lblMessage.Text = "No file attached."
End If
```

The files do, in fact, upload to my `VIRTUAL_REC_DOCS` folder and saves to the database.

After data binding, the items display in the form's HyperLink control.

[image: screenshot]

For whatever reason, clicking the HyperLink does **NOT** open the item.

Is there a problem with the way the NavigateUrl is displaying the path or is something else going on?

Comment: You need a relative path to the upload folder, not the absolute from the C drive.

Comment: Is there a simple solution? `NavigateUrl='<%# Bind(Server.MapPath("doc_path")) %>'` does not work.

Comment: See Claudio Redi's answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a physical path but you need to use the file Url. `NavigateUrl` should be something like

```
NavigateUrl='<%# YourPageClassName.VIRTUAL_REC_DOCS + Bind("doc_name") %>'
```

Where `YourPageClassName` is the name of your page class.

Comment: The page does not like my `VIRTUAL_REC_DOCS` defined in code behind. How would I define this in the HTML?

Comment: @jp2code just change `item.doc_path` to be `VIRTUAL_REC_DOCS + item.doc_name`.

Comment: @jp2code: where's `VIRTUAL_REC_DOCS` defined? is part of the page class?

Comment: It is defined at the top of the code behind: `Protected Const VIRTUAL_REC_DOCS As String = "~/ReqTrackerDocs/"`. Isn't my file uploading routine already doing this: `item.doc_path = uploadDir & fuFooter.FileName` (where uploadDir is Server.MapPath(VIRTUAL_REC_DOCS))?

Comment: @jp2code: it does the opossite: converts a url into a physical path. BTW, updated my answer